# Copy VB.NET code from Visual Studio Express to Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Is it possible to develop forms in Visual Studio Express, and copy the VB.NET code to Microsoft Access 2013? Because I'm not familiar with Visual Basic code in Microsoft Access.

Comment: No.  Access uses VBA, which is nowhere near the same thing as VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Microsoft Access uses VBA (Visual Basic for Application) and VBA is a different Language than VB.NET.

Sure, you could write your DLL in a NET Language of your choice and call that DLL from Microsoft Access VBA code, but it is not an easy task.

[Here there is a project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18939/C-Com) that explain how to build a COM visible NET library that is callable from a VBA code. It is in C# but the principles are the same, just search for different syntax if really want to do it

Comment: @Tim and Steve, thanks for your reply. The project I'm working on is developed by using Visual Studio 2012 Express. Is it possible to display data using reports I created in Access? Or is it possible to use Report Builder 3.0 to display data stored in Access?

Comment: You can reach and manipulate any kind of data stored in the database (accdb or mdb) using the classes provided by the System.Data.OleDb namespace. I am pretty convinced that you cannot use the report objects stored in access, but I am not enough expert on this interoperability to rule it out.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express edition which does not have reporting tool. Can you please suggest other tools to display data beside DataGridView? Thanks.

Comment: [There is an high voted article on Codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580947/NET-Reporting-Tool-Tutorial-1) about a free reporting tool called [ReportMax available from this site](http://www.cppmax.com/). I don't use it, so I really can't say if it works with express neither I can suggest to use or not. At least it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I Thing if you know vb.net you should be able to learn "VBA" in no time is **almost** the same